# counting data in csv file that has 2 columns

Tags: c++, csv

I'm having trouble counting the number of elements in each column of a 2 column .csv file. I wrote a small code below but it's wrong and I'm not sure how to approach. Please advise! Thank you!

```
while(!inFile.eof()) //While the original file is open, the # of lines is counted.
{
    inFile>>datafile[i++][i++]; //this counts the data in each column
}
cout<<"The length of the original data file is "<<[i]<<[i]<<"."<<endl;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Good question, but you should explain what's wrong with more exact detail, like what output you get vs what you expect, or what exact errors you're getting.

Comment: Consider writing a small for-loop that runs 10 times and doesn't actually do any memory access. Print out the value of `i` at the end of each iteration and again after the loop is done. See the problem yet? Hint: you're using the same variable to index both the rows and the columns - _that's_ going to end in tears, as you see. The last access in such a scenario would be to datafile[19][19] - you've spread 20 memory accesses over some 400 locations in memory..

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `datafile` is declared as something like this:

`int datafile[256][2];`

The first set of square brackets is for the row, and the second set of square brackets is for the column. (It could be the other way round.) And your variable `i` is counting which row you're inputting data to - it could be renamed `row`, in fact.

So you don't want to be putting `i` or `row` in the brackets which choose the column... is that enough to give you a foothold?